# CORS 403 on React JS

Tags: reactjs, spring-boot, cors

************************* Solution ******************************

0.- Add in your POM

```
 <dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-security</artifactId>
 </dependency>
```

0.1-Add in yours project the packages.project.bla.bla.bla.Configs

1.- In Config . Packages create 3 Class

```
    -CorsConfiguration.java
    -CorsFilter.java
    -WebSecurityConfig.java
```

2.- On your CorsConfiguration.java

```
    @Configuration
@EnableWebMvc
public class CorsConfiguration implements WebMvcConfigurer
{
    @Override
    public void addCorsMappings(CorsRegistry registry) {
        registry.addMapping("/**")
                .allowedMethods("GET", "POST", "PUT", "DELETE");
    }

    @Bean
    public WebMvcConfigurer corsConfigurer() 
    {
        return new WebMvcConfigurer() {
            @Override
            public void addCorsMappings(CorsRegistry registry) {
                registry.addMapping("/**").allowedOrigins("http://YOURSPRINGSERVER:PORT", "http://YOURFRONT/REACT/WHATEVERSERVER:PORT");
            }
        };
    }
```

Note: here it will give access to any front server registred that queries from the root URI and, all verbs methods ("GET", "POST", "PUT", "DELETE")

3.- on your CorsFilter.java

```
    @Override
    public void doFilter(ServletRequest servletRequest, ServletResponse 
        servletResponse, FilterChain filterChain) throws IOException, ServletException {
        HttpServletResponse response = (HttpServletResponse) servletResponse;
        HttpServletRequest request= (HttpServletRequest) servletRequest;

        response.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
        response.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Methods", 
        "GET,POST,DELETE,PUT,OPTIONS");
        response.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "*");
        response.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Credentials", true);
        response.setHeader("Access-Control-Max-Age", 180);
        filterChain.doFilter(servletRequest, servletResponse);
       }
```

Notes: this class defines the responses of the html headers of the controllers

4.-And finally in your WebSecurityConfig.class

```
        @Configuration
    @EnableWebSecurity
    @EnableGlobalMethodSecurity(prePostEnabled = true)
    public class WebSecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {
    @Autowired
        public void configureGlobal(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {

        }

        @Bean
        public PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder() {
            return new BCryptPasswordEncoder();
        }

        @Bean
        CorsFilter corsFilter() {
            CorsFilter filter = new CorsFilter();
            return filter;
        }

        @Override
        protected void configure(HttpSecurity httpSecurity) throws Exception {      
            httpSecurity
            .addFilterBefore(corsFilter(), SessionManagementFilter.class) 
            .csrf().disable()
            .authorizeRequests()
            .antMatchers("/raps/**").permitAll();
        }}
```

and ready all the queries made from the front will be accepted and you can also add some TOKEN as JWT without problems

---

I have the following problem, now I am training with a React + Axios login, but when I try a post-login method, the following error appears:

**Chrome Console**

```
OPTIONS http://localhost:8081/usuario/auth 403

Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'http://localhost:8081/usuario/auth' from origin 'http://localhost:3000' has been blocked by CORS policy: Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.
```

**Ajax Method**

```
handleLogin(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    console.log(this.state)
    axios.post(`http://localhost:8081/usuario/auth`, this.state )
      .then(res => {
        console.log(res);
        console.log(res.data);
      })

    this.props.onAddUser(this.state);
  }
```

**The Request Headers**

```
Accept: */*
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate, br
Accept-Language: es-CL,es-US;q=0.9,es;q=0.8,en-US;q=0.7,en;q=0.6,es-419;q=0.5
Access-Control-Request-Headers: content-type
Access-Control-Request-Method: POST
Connection: keep-alive
Host: localhost:8081
Origin: http://localhost:3000
Referer: http://localhost:3000/
Sec-Fetch-Mode: cors
Sec-Fetch-Site: same-site
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/79.0.3945.79 Safari/537.36
```

**Object on React ** 
`{email: "manuel@gmail.com", password: "ghgg1255"}`

**Back end**

```
package com.raps.controller;

import...

@RestController
@CommonsLog
@CrossOrigin
@RequestMapping(value = "/raps/usuario", produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
public class UsuarioController {

    @Autowired
    private UsuarioService uService; 

    @GetMapping
    public Iterable<Usuario> getAll(){... thats work ...}

    @GetMapping("/{id}")
    public Optional<Usuario> getById(@PathVariable int id) {... thats work ...}

    @PostMapping("/auth")
    public Optional<Usuario> auth(@RequestBody Usuario usuario) {
        log.info("Controller");
        return uService.auth(usuario);
    }

}
```

I have read about the origin of the problem but it is not possible to solve it for post methods. I ask for your help and guidance regarding this.

The git code: https://github.com/CaptMoar/RaPService/tree/Seba

Answer (score 0, accepted):

open up your package.json

Add in an attribute that reads

```
"proxy":"localhost8081"
```

Change all of your post requests to drop the localhost8081 part, so that they'd just be something like

```
axios.post("/usuario/auth",this.state)
```

The React dev server will now spoof your address to be the same as that of the back end (only possible in development mode-- modern web browsers are too clever for that on a deployed link), and should enable you to bypass your CORS error. if that isn't working, change your proxy to your IP address.

Comment: Change the .Json and this not when making queries now use the url "http: // localhost: 3000 / user / auth" which throws a 404 through the ports.

Comment: I think you have a typo or two in your response, and right now I'm having a difficult time reading it. Is there any way you could edit it to make it a little bit more clear for me? I'm not entirely certain what you've done and what is happening.

Answer (score 0):

You need to add a CORS filter in order to allow cross-origin requests. Below is an example that allow all methods, headers, you can specify methods and headers to be allowed instead of allowing all.

```
@CrossOrigin
public class CorsFilter extends OncePerRequestFilter{

@Override
protected void doFilterInternal(final HttpServletRequest request, final HttpServletResponse response, final FilterChain filterChain) throws ServletException, IOException {
        response.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
        response.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Methods","*");
        response.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Headers","*");
 filterChain.doFilter(request, response);
    }
}
```

Comment: researching about your solution in my project did not have a middleware / security layer. so adding Spring Security and @EnableWebSecurity activates the queries '*'

``